# Remove entry from classpath after compile

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a legacy war project that depends on a jar project, the jar project needs to add a few unmanaged jars to the **classpath** for compilation. But these jars should not be packaged in the war. So my question is how do I remove these entries from the **fullClasspath**. The following won't work:

```
val excludeFilter = "(servlet-api.jar)|(gwt-dev.jar)|(gwt-user.jar)"
val filteredCP = cp.flatMap({ entry =>
   val jar = entry.data.getName()
   if (jar.matches(excludeFilter)) {
     Nil
   } else {
     Seq(entry)
   }
})
fullClasspath in Runtime = filteredCP
```

I am pretty sure there must be simple way to do this but so far it has eluded me.

**Edit**: Based on Pablo's sugestion to use the managed classpath instead of the unmanaged I can rephrase the question as: **how do you add local jars to the managedClasspath**. My jars are placed in a local folder with a (very) nonstandard layout:

```
lib/testng.jar
lib/gwt/2.3/gwt-user.jar
lib/jetty/servlet.jar
```

So basically I am looking for something like:

```
libraryDependencies += "testng" % "provided->test"
libraryDependencies += "gwt" % "2.3" % "gwt-user" % "provided->compile"
libraryDependencies += "jetty" % "servlet" % "provided->default"
```

allowing me to grab jars from my own local lib folder.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some information is provided on the [Classpaths](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths) page, but it is not very clear or detailed.  The information is also available using the `inspect` command, described on the [Inspecting Settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Inspecting-Settings) page.

Basically, for a configuration X, in a short-hand notation:

```
// complete, exported classpath, such as used by 
//   'run', 'test', 'console', and the war task
fullClasspath in X =
  dependencyClasspath in X ++ exportedProducts in X

// classpath only containing dependencies, 
//   used by 'compile' or 'console-quick', for example
dependencyClasspath in X =
  externalDependencyClasspath in X ++ internalDependencyClasspath in X

// classpath containing only dependencies external to the build
//  (as opposed to the inter-project dependencies in internalDependencyClasspath)
externalDependencyClasspath in X =
  unmanagedClasspath in X ++ managedClasspath in X

// the manually provided classpath
unmanagedClasspath in X =
  unmanagedJars for X and all configurations X extends, transitively
```

So, normally, when you want to add unmanaged libraries, you add them to `unmanagedJars`.  For example, if you add libraries to `unmanagedJars in Compile`, then sbt will correctly include the libraries on the `unmanagedClasspath` for `Compile`, `Runtime`, and `Test`.

However, you want explicit control here.  Add the libraries only to the `unmanagedClasspath` you want the jars on, which is `unmanagedClasspath in Compile`.  For example, in sbt 0.11.0+:

```
unmanagedClasspath in Compile <++= baseDirectory map { base =>
  val lib = base / "lib"
  Seq(
    lib / "testng.jar",
    lib / "gwt/2.3/gwt-user.jar",
    lib / "jetty/servlet.jar"
  )
}
```

Assuming the war plugin uses the Runtime classpath, those jars will only show up on the compile classpath and not in the war.

Answer (score 4):

sbt supports [ivy-like configurations](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Configurations), and implements maven basic scopes.

If you want to use some jars in your compilation classpath but don't want to ship them, I guess the `provided` scope is for you:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.example" % "example" % "1.0" % "provided->compile"
```

Comment: I was thinking about this, the problem is that we cannot (company policy, that I cannot change) use libs that are downloaded automatically (including their transitive dependencies). Thus each eclipse project has a lib folder where the jars are placed and I have been unable to find a example on using libraryDependencies with jars placed locally (inside the project) in a non ivy/maven layout (fx /lib/gwt/2.3/gwt-user.jar /lib/gwt/2.3/gwt-dev.jar ...).