# how to get internal project dependency jar path in SBT

Tags: sbt

I am implementing custom deploy Task in SBT and I need to copy all required jars to deployment folder.
I am able to get paths to all external dependencies using `update` TaskKey. Unfortunately updateReport does not include internal dependencies.
Here is my simple configuration

```
val deploy = TaskKey[Unit]("deploy","deploy")

lazy val projectA = Project(id=project-a,
settings=Project.defaultSettings)

lazy val projectB = Project(id=project-b,
settings=Project.defaultSettings) dependsOn(projectA)

lazy val projectC = Project(id=project-c,
settings=Project.defaultSettings, ++ Seq(deployTask)) dependsOn(projectB)

val deployTask = deploy <<= (update) map {(updateReport) =>
val externalDependency = updateReport.allFiles //paths to all external dependencies are available here
//project-a.jar and project-b.jar are not here
}
```

So, the question is how can I obtain absolute path to internal project dependencies i.e. project-a.jar, project-b.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the [`exportJars`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/howto/package.html) property:

```
exportJars := true
```

then

```
exportedProducts in Compile
```

Should give you the path to the jar file for a project:

```
> show export-jars
[info] true
> show exported-products
[info] List(Attributed(/Users/luke/Work/myproject/server/target/scala-2.9.2/server_2.9.2-0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar))
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 5, 2012 11:29:51 PM
```

Comment: To add to this, you can just go through classpaths to get the jars.  The different classpaths are described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7862872/850196.