# sbt unmanagedClasspath entry for lift compiles but not found at runtime

Tags: scala, sbt, lift

I have an unmanagedClasspath entry in my lift sbt file that points to the classes for an external java project. It compiles fine but I get a NoClassDefError when it runs. Below is the sbt entry followed by some of the trace of the NoClassDefError.

Any help much appreciated

Des

```
unmanagedClasspath in Compile += file("[Path to my project]/classes")

 ERROR n.liftweb.http.provider.HTTPProvider - Failed to Boot! Your application may not run properly
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myproject/MyClass
    at bootstrap.liftweb.Boot.boot(Boot.scala:70) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at net.liftweb.util.ClassHelpers$$anonfun$createInvoker$1.apply(ClassHelpers.scala:364) ~[lift-util_2.9.1-2.5-RC2.jar:2.5-RC2]
    at net.liftweb.util.ClassHelpers$$anonfun$createInvoker$1.apply(ClassHelpers.scala:362) ~[lift-util_2.9.1-2.5-RC2.jar:2.5-RC2]
    at net.liftweb.http.DefaultBootstrap$$anonfun$boot$1.apply(LiftRules.scala:1999) ~[lift-webkit_2.9.1-2.5-RC2.jar:2.5-RC2]
    at net.liftweb.http.DefaultBootstrap$$anonfun$boot$1.apply(LiftRules.scala:1999) ~[lift-webkit_2.9.1-2.5-RC2.jar:2.5-RC2]
    at net.liftweb.common.Full.map(Box.scala:553) ~[lift-common_2.9.1-2.5-RC2.jar:2.5-RC2]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`unmanagedJars in Compile`  is used as base for the same key in `Runtime` and `Test`, so its content is inherited by `Runtime`, but this is not the case for `unmanagedClasspath`. That's why you should prefer `unmanagedJars` when possible.

You can explicitly add your folder to both configurations:

```
val additionalClasses = file("[Path to my project]/classes")

unmanagedClasspath in Compile += additionalClasses

unmanagedClasspath in Runtime += additionalClasses
```

*Note*: sbt < 0.13 doesn't support `val` in `build.sbt`, so you have to duplicate its content in both settings, or switch to a full `Build.scala`.

See the [Classpaths docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Classpaths.html) and [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7862872/738138) for more details on what the classpath settings do and how they are inherited between configurations.

I could not think of a way to add it to both at the same time though...

Comment: Thank you that worked. The only thing is that sbt didn't like the syntax of the first line so I could not use the additionalClasses definition but had to add the class path explicitly for both Compile and Runtime

Comment: oh, you mean the `val`? Right, you cannot add a `val` in a `build.sbt` in sbt < 0.13.  You have to either duplicate the `file(...)` or use a `Build.scala` file. I'll edit the answer.